# Issue with .Net TargetingPack installation following a Visual Studio installation

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, installation

After installing Visual Studio 2019 (or 2017, tried with both) via the Visual Studio Installer,
I get the message "Couldn't install Microsoft.Net.4.5.2.TargetingPack", 
[seen here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q4VGu.png).
Consulting the error log shows the error code is 1625, which corresponds to: `This installation is forbidden by system policy. Contact your system administrator.`

The only solution I found for this is to execute Visual Studio Installer as Administrator, naturally though it didn't work!

So I then tried to directly install the .Net Framework 4.5.2 Developer Pack found here: https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download/visual-studio-sdks?utm_source=getdotnetsdk&utm_medium=referral

And this installation fails with a new error message: `Installation failed with error code: (0x80092010), "The certificate has been revoked.".` I have been on this error for a full day and I haven't found anything so far...

Please help!

Answer (score 0):

> Issue with .Net TargetingPack installation following a Visual Studio
> installation

**First**, based on your description that two programs are installed with errors, **you should make sure that your current user account has the right to read and write to the current agent.**

To confirm this, you need to contact the administrator account.

**Besides**, if your account has the right to install these programs, you should try these suggestions:

**1)** delete any caches under temp folder(`C:\Users\xxx(user account)\AppData\Local\Temp`)

**2)** turn off any firewall and antivirus software

**3)** open **Control Panel**-->**Administrative Tools**-->**Local Security Settings**-->**Software Restriction Policies**

**Note**: If no software restrictions are defined, right click the Software Restriction Policies node and select **New Software Restriction Policy**-->Double click **Enforcement**--> Select `All users except Local Administrators`

Restart the computer for the changes to take effect and After this, run visual studio installer as administrator to retry the install.

**4)** or just try to  [Turn off Windows Installer](https://www.sync.com/help/installation-error-1625/#:%7E:text=Error%20%231625%20is%20a%20Windows,To%20check%3A&text=Under%20your%20name%2C%20it%20would%20indicate%20if%20you%20are%20an%20Administrator.).

**5)** if you have any updates on your OS, please try to update them.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Sadly none of these suggestions worked :(

Comment: It is quite strange. Did you try to use an administrator account to test it? You should make sure that your current account has the right to install them.

Comment: To test it, I suggest you could try to install net core 3.1 developer pack or net framework 4.8 developer pack to test whether they can be installed. Besides, please right-click on the `installer.exe`->Properties-->Digital Signatures-->click every entry-->Details-->View Certificate-->make sure that the certificates are installed and they are valid and trusted.

Comment: In addition, if these do not help, you can try to use [vscollect tool](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=12493) to share the whole log with us to troubleshoot the issue more quickly. It usually exists under `%TEMP%vslogs.zip`. See [this](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/setup/visual-studio-and-net-log-collection-utility/).